# How to replace column value with binary value in python?

Tags: python

how can i replace column value to binary value in python, for example i have this table:

```
age | height
------------
20  | 160
30  | 173
21  | 174
32  | 165
13  | 140
26  | 160
40  | 164
10  | 131
11  | 140
```

I want to change the value of each column to binary value, for example for age column, i want to change the value to "<30" and ">=30", and for height column to "<160" and ">=160"

I already tried using :

```
mask = df[0] < 30
df.loc[mask, 0] = "<30"

mask2 = df[0] >= 30
df.loc[mask2, 0] = ">=30"
```

but i want it more simple

Comment: What format is this table in? Is it from a text file?

Comment: And the real question is: what do you have tried so far?

Comment: it is a csv file

Comment: if this is a pandas dataframe please add this information on the question and tag it accordingly

Comment: Are you reading the csv file in someway? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(<yourcsvfile>)
df['age'] = np.where(df['age'] >= 30, ">=30", "<=30")
df['height'] = np.where(df['height'] >= 160, ">=160", "<=160")
```